# Spark job (Java) cannot write data to Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am using *Docker 17.04.0-ce* and *Compose 1.12.0 in Windows* in order to deploy *Elasticsearch* cluster (version 5.4.0)  over Docker.
So far I have done the following:

1) I have created a single Elasticsearch node via compose with the following configuration

```
  elasticsearch1:
    build: elasticsearch/
    container_name: es_1
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud1
      - node.master=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      docker_elk:
        aliases:
          - elasticsearch
```

This results in the node being deployed, but it is not accessible from Spark. I write data as

```
JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(aggregators.toDF(), collectionName +"/record");
```

and I get the following error, although the node is running

```
I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
```

2) I found out that this problem is solved if I add the following line in the node configuration

```
- network.publish_host=${ENV_IP}
```

3) Then I created similar configurations for 2 additional nodes as

```
  elasticsearch1:
    build: elasticsearch/
    container_name: es_1
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud1
      - node.master=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - network.publish_host=${ENV_IP}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      docker_elk:
        aliases:
          - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch2:
    build: elasticsearch/
    container_name: es_2
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud2
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
      - node.master=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
      - 9301:9300
    networks:
      - docker_elk

  elasticsearch3:
    build: elasticsearch/
    container_name: es_3
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
      - node.name=cloud3
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
      - node.master=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - esdata3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9200
      - 9302:9300
    networks:
      - docker_elk
```

This results in a cluster of 3 nodes being created successfully. However the same error reappeared in Spark and data cannot be written to the cluster. I get the same behavior even if I add `network.publish_host` to all nodes.

Regarding Spark, I use *elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11* version 5.4.0 (same as ES version). Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this. Apart from setting `es.nodes` and `es.port` in Spark, the problem goes away if I set `es.nodes.wan.only` to `true`.

Comment: This solved my issue. Spark app trying to write to ES running in a docker container was hanging until I set this property. Thanks

Comment: I suppose this is the correct answer. However, I didn't get why this property is needed on the local machine. I guess we use it only in the AWS/Cloud env? And I faced this issue on Mac m1 pro processor, on Linux I have never had such a problem. For me it something a weird situation.